# what is that up side arrow before the number 10 in the constant method instance below?

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

To make it clear and concise:

```
1. What is it?
2. Why is it there?
3. How to type it with a normal Keyboard?
4. Thanks!
```

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Squeak Smalltalk vertical arrow in code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7819960/squeak-smalltalk-vertical-arrow-in-code)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's `^` symbol. :) A return statement in smalltalk.

I don't know if it's default listing's feature in latex, but upward arrow is being used of `^`.

On normal keyboard you can type this symbol by pressing *Shift* + *6*

Answer (score 6):

Just for the record, in old versions of Pharo, the `^` character was printed as an "up arrow".
So, as Yuriy says type `^` to get the "up arrow" return.

That behavior does not exist any more in latest versions of Pharo: ^ is printed as `^`.